# MinGW/GCC Delay Loaded DLL equivalent?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, mingw, visual-c++

I'm trying to port some old MSVC C++ code to MinGW/GCC.

One problem is that the project relies heavily on the /DELAYLOAD option for functions that aren't always used, and where the proper dll is located at runtime.

Is there such a similar option on MinGW/GCC?

This code is targeting the windows platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On elf targets (for Unix-like systems), you can specify the `-z lazy` option (which is the default anyway) with `ld` (the linker that MinGW also uses).

As far as I know, the i386 PE target (for Windows) **does not** have an explicit lazy linking option. I can find no documentation of it being available.

Comment: That's most unfortunate. I'll have to come up with some sort of workaround. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I do not think this is correct answer. `-z lazy` enables delayed symbol resolution but shared library is always loaded. `/DELAYLOAD` enables delayed linking i.e. delays load of library until one of it's functions is called (Solaris has this feature but it didn't get to Glibc because Drepper^W^W for some reason).

Comment: @yugr is right, gcc has lazy load only for symbols (which is the default anyway) and it will load the library at startup anyway, not covering the purpose of MSVC `/DELAYLOAD` at all

Answer (score 7):

And I would add that, although delay-load DLLs appear to be a part of the Windows OS, they're actually implemented in terms of small stubs generated by the linker. At least, this used to be the case. So there is no formal notion of "delay loading" at the Windows OS level. There's a convention, based on binary code emitted by the linker.

Comment: Not really Windows specific, other operating systems implement delay loading the same way.

Comment: There is now, since WIndows 10. See `QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--output-delaylib` argument to `dlltool` to create a delay-loaded import library. You can then link against the generated import library to delay load the DLL.

As an example of lazy loading an existing DLL, let's say you want to lazy-load the Windows DLL `version.dll`, which exports `GetFileVersionInfoSizeW`. First, we define with functions we want to call in a `version.def` file:

```
EXPORTS
 GetFileVersionInfoSizeW
```

We then can create an delay-loaded import library with `dlltool`:

```
dlltool --input-def version.def --output-delaylib version.lib --dllname version.dll
```

When linking, use the resulting `version.lib`:

```
gcc -o test test.c -lversion -L .
```

The full version of this example is available on [my GitHub](https://github.com/AustinWise/delay-load-mingw).

Fun fact: This feature likely was not available in released software at the time this question was asked. The feature was commited [three months](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=10e636d21ea3e704dca34a6393fdefd1e90f07c8) before this question was asked.

Comment: This seems to work with ld, but segfaults with lld (`clang++ -fuse-ld=lld`) when trying to write to read-only memory. Any idea what's wrong? Is the linker merging sections that it isn't supposed to?